What is this 2D black-and-white pixel art Metroidvania game that’s similar to Hollow Knight? [Probably lost media]
I recently bought a used computer, and while checking files, I found this picture of a game. I asked the seller, and he said he doesn’t remember the name, but he told me it’s a 2D Metroidvania game very similar to Hollow Knight.

The screenshot shows a minimalist black-and-white pixel art game scene, where a character with spiky black hair stands in the center of the image. To the right stands a small creature, resembling a bunny or rodent, rendered in the same pixel art style.
In the upper portion of the image, gray-toned mountains or hills form the background. A feather or leaf-shaped object floats to the left of the main character.
The file is named "Captura de pantalla 2021-08-16 171306." I'm from Mexico, so in English, it would be "Screenshot 2021-08-16 171306," if I’m not mistaken.
The file dates are the same as in the filename, "Monday, August 16, 2021, 05:13:06 p.m." The creation and modification dates are the same.
The directory is the Documents folder. I think he used the "Snipping Tool" application.
The seller told me he played it for a bit and then closed it. He mentioned he didn't play it much, so he doesn’t remember much about it. He also said he doesn’t have anything like it in his Steam account, so it must be from another store, though he couldn’t remember which one.
Recently, the seller and I were talking, and he mentioned that he remembered the game has 'pid' in its name. This doesn't mean that 'pid' is the name of the game, but that 'pid' is somewhere in the name.
Does anyone know what it's called?
(If you want to post this query on other websites, I don't mind; on the contrary, I would like it to reach more people.)

I searched Google for the image, and it wasn’t able to find anything. It’s possible this is a small passion project or a game that never got released.

@Daemons It might be a very small project; I didn’t find anything either. If I have more information, I will write it down immediately.

This doesn't seem a real game, there's no UI

@pinckerman It doesnt appear to be a full screenshot, just a partial one using Snipping Tool.

Maybe I'm just going crazy or having Deja Vu, but both of those characters look familiar, as if I've seen a banner on Steam that uses them or something.

@pinckerman it can be just a piece of the screen, or the game may not have an interface. For example, Undertale doesn’t have one (the part where you move around the map).

Looks like it could be an itch.io indie game.

@galacticninja It's most likely, my theory is that the game was uploaded to some platform and, since it went unnoticed, it was deleted.

In simple terms, I believe this game is Knytt Stories because of the style and the amount of custom maps. (If I find the actual map, I will edit the answer.) I have found some simple evidence, like a character that looks almost 1 to 1 to the image that was provided.

Also, there are characters that face you.

Although this might have been a far stretch and doesn't look like the game image provided. The style of the game is the same, and there are many custom maps available, which also exist in black and white and with custom characters, background, etc.

Hi oelimoe, I can't find images of the protagonist facing forward (and the wild black hair is the only thing that make them look alike), nor can I find images of the game in the same greyscale that the OP's picture has.

@Joachim i am not sure if this is the game but its highly possible it has many custom maps which are not all played alot with custom structures and characters. indeed the greyscale doesnt exactly match there are for sure levels that are white black grey

Thank you for your response, I will try to play the game and search for maps to see if it really matches. I was looking at images of the game and what I suspect is about the characters and the colors; I feel they don't look very similar. Again, thank you for responding!
